# Is "Target F# runtime:" of "N/A" nominal?

Tags: f#

In Visual Studio 2013.4 I have an F# project and looking at its properties I see that the "Target F# runtime:" is "N/A" and the drop down box is disabled.

In the same solution there are many other F# projects. They all have a "Target F# runtime:" of F# 3.1 (FSharp.Core, 4.3.1.0).

BTW the "Target Framework:" is .NET Framework 4.5.

Is "Target F# runtime:" of "N/A" nominal or do we have a problem Houston?

Answer (score 6):

I compared it to another project and it was missing this element in the *.fsproj

```
<Reference Include="FSharp.Core, Version=$(TargetFSharpCoreVersion), Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

After adding that, the "Target F# runtime:" stopped being yeah, nah and was F# 3.1 (FSharp.Core, 4.3.1.0).

Comment: Good find! I notice also that this sometimes happens (can't put my finger to it when exactly) when you convert a project from one Visual Studio version to another. Or when you manually edit the fsproj file and VS can't make heads or tails of it anymore.